# Prove that any integer divisible by 3 can be written as a sum of cubes of four integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

My book says only this:
$$6k = (k+1)^3 + (k-1)^3 + (-k)^3 + (-k)^3$$
$$6k - 15 = (2k)^3 + (-2k-1)^3 + (k-2)^3 + (-k-2)^3$$
I want to know how it got to these expressions. Using trial and error will take a lot of time.

Comment: usually in books they just spit out whatever equation holds true when they need it. it is hard to get this insight (kind of like P vs NP; easy to verify but hard to come up with) but they are saying this insight is here. It is hard to tell you exactly how to get that

Answer (score 4):

You can verify them by expanding the cubes on the right side and noting that it comes out right.  Once you do, note that every number divisible by $3$ can be written in one of those two forms, which proves the proposition.  If you want the first one, it is not hard to find.  It is natural to consider $(k+1)^3+(k-1)^3=2k^3+6k$ and then note that you can subtract off two $k^3$s to get there.  Now you have shown that every number divisible by $6$ is the sum of four cubes and it is natural to try to extend the result.

Answer (score 2):

The question is about expressing an integer as the sum of four cubes.

You asked:

> I want to know how it got to these expressions.

The key is that cubes can be positive or negative and the difference of
consecutive cubes is quadratic. For example,

$$ (k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1. \tag1 $$

Furthermore, the difference of two consecutive differences is linear.

$$ ((k\!+\!1)^3\!-\!k^3)\!-\!(k^3\!-\!(k\!-\!1)^3)\!=\!
(3k^2\!+\!3k\!+\!1)\!-\!(3k^2\!-\!3k\!+\!1)\!=\!6k. \tag2 $$

This implies the first expression you quoted:

$$ 6k \!=\! (k\!+\!1)^3\!-\!k^3\!-\!k^3 + (k\!-\!1)^3\!=\!
(k\!+\!1)^3\!+\!(k\!-\!1)^3\!+\!(-k)^3\!+\!(-k)^3. \tag3 $$

Notice that $\,6k\,$ is always even, that the cube of an odd
number is odd and the cube of an even number is even. Thus, to
express an odd number as the sum of four cubes, either exactly
one of the cubes must be odd or exactly three of the cubes must be odd. So in the first equation replace $\,k\,$ with $\,2k\,$ to get

$$(2k+1)^3 - (2k)^3 = 12k^2 + 6k + 1. \tag4 $$

Now the difference of the cubes of numbers that differ by two is

$$ (k\!+\!1)^3\!-\!(k\!-\!1)^3\!=\!(k^3\!+\!3k^2\!+\!3k\!+\!1)
\!-\!(k^3\!-\!3k^2\!+\!3k\!-\!1)\!=\!6k^2\!+\!2 \tag5 $$

which is too small but the difference of the cubes of numbers
that differ by four is

$$ (k\!+\!2)^3\!-\!(k\!-\!2)^3\!=\!(k^3\!+\!6k^2\!+\!12k\!+\!8)
\!-\!(k^3\!-\!6k^2\!+\!12k\!-\!8)\!=\!12k^2\!+\!16. \tag6 $$

Combine equations $(4)$ and $(6)$ to get the second expression you quoted:

$$  6k - 15 = (2k+1)^3 + (-2k)^3 + (k-2)^3 + (-k-2)^3. \tag7 $$

Answer (score 0):

The required representations look as so called mathematical folklore.
They look not so complicated, so I think they could be found even more or less accidentally during some elementary number theory investigations or exercises. But if you want a rational reconstruction then we can relate the representations to a counterpart of [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) for  integers. Looking for simple parametric families of representations, we can look for expressions $a_ik+b_i$ linear in $k$ with integer coefficients such that in the sum of their cubes the coefficients at $k^3$ and $k^2$ cancel and there remains an expression linear in $k$.

Comment: Is there no other way to prove this? I don't know why but I just don't like this method of proving. Even when the steps are explained just like @mathlove did. This approach seems extremely isolated in the sense that this method of proof isn't really teaching me anything about any other problem. I just don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know another proof, but I think I can show some steps to get $$6k = (k+1)^3 + (-k)^3+ (k-1)^3  + (-k)^3$$
$$6k-15=(2k+1)^3 + (-2k)^3 +(k-2)^3+ (-k-2)^3$$

Let us start with
$$(ak+b)^3+(ck+d)^3+(ek+f)^3+(gk+h)^3\tag1$$
which can be written as
$$(1)=(a^3+c^3+e^3+g^3) k^3 + 3(a^2 b+c^2d+e^2f+g^2h) k^2 + 3(a b^2+cd^2+ef^2+gh^2) k + b^3 + d^3 + f^3 + h^3 $$

So, we want to have $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)$ satisfying
$$\begin{cases}a^3+c^3+e^3+g^3=0
\\a^2b+c^2d+e^2f+g^2h=0
\\\text{$|b^3+d^3+f^3+h^3|$ is small}\end{cases}$$

Here, it should be natural to take $(c,g)=(-a,-e)$.

So, we want to have $(a,b,d,e,f,h)$ satisfying
$$\begin{cases}a^2b+a^2d+e^2f+e^2h=0
\\\text{$|b^3+d^3+f^3+h^3|$ is small}\end{cases}$$

If we take $(f,h)=(-b,-d)$ for which $b^3+d^3+f^3+h^3=0$ holds, then $$(1)= 3(a-e)\color{red}{(a+e)(b+d)}k^2 + 3\color{red}{(a+e)(b+d)}(b-d)k $$ Here, taking $e=a$, we have $(1)=6a(b^2-d^2)k$. So, we can take $(a,b,d)=(1,1,0)$ to have $$6k = (k+1)^3 + (-k)^3+ (k-1)^3  + (-k)^3$$

So, we are happy if we can find $(a,b,d,e,f,h)$ satisfying
$$\begin{cases}|a|,|b|,|d|,|e|,|f|,|h|\le 2
\\a^2b+a^2d+e^2f+e^2h=0
\\\text{$|b^3+d^3+f^3+h^3|$ is a small odd integer divisible by $3$}
\\a b^2+cd^2+ef^2-eh^2=2\end{cases}$$ Here, taking $d=0$ and $h=f$, we want to solve
$$\begin{cases}|a|,|b|,|e|,|f|\le 2
\\a^2b+2e^2f=0
\\\text{$|b^3+2f^3|$ is a small odd integer divisible by $3$}
\\a b^2=2\end{cases}$$ We have $a=2$ and $|b|=1$. Taking $b=1$, we get $(e,f)=(\pm 1,-2)$ for which we have $$6k-15=(2k+1)^3 + (-2k)^3 +(k-2)^3+ (-k-2)^3$$